# Window with image GTK C++

Tags: c++, image, interface, gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to open a new window from an existing window by clicking on a button. The new window should display an image. When I click the button, the new window is shown, but the image is not displayed. There are no errors.

I made sure that my image is in the current directory and is readable. What is happening?

Code:

```
void ExampleWindow::on_button_clicked()
{
    std::cout << "The Button was clicked." << std::endl;
    Gtk::Window *window = new Gtk::Window();
    Gtk::VBox mainLayout; 
    window->add(mainLayout);
    Gtk::Image image("Vampire.png");
    mainLayout.pack_start(image);
 

    window->show_all(); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that "Vampire.png" is located in your working directory when you launch the app? Try to read it as a text to verify.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after your handler is called (end of scope), all local variables are destroyed, and that includes `image`.

Here is code that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <gtkmm.h>

class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:

    ExampleWindow()
    : m_image("Vampire.png")
    {
        add(m_btn);
        m_btn.signal_clicked().connect([this](){OnButtonClicked();});
    }

private:

    void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " enter scope" << std::endl;

        m_window = std::make_unique<Gtk::Window>();
        m_window->add(m_image);
        m_window->show_all();

        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " leaving scope" << std::endl;

        // With your code, image is destroyed here. The window still
        // lives because it was newed, but you lost your reference to
        // it and so the program will leak memory (i.e. you will be
        // unable to call delete on it, unless it is a class member).
    }

    Gtk::Button m_btn("Show image");
    Gtk::Image m_image;
    std::unique_ptr<Gtk::Window> m_window;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "so.question.q65011763");
    
    ExampleWindow window;
    window.show_all();

    return app->run(window);

    // With this code, the image and the window are both destroyed here.
    // Since the window is in a unique_ptr, delete will be automatically
    // called on it.
}
```

Note that I have made all variables class members, so that they outlive the end of scope of the handler. I have also stored the window containing the image inside a smart pointer so that I don't have to call `delete` myself.